# How to Create Deterministic Guids

Tags: c#, .net, guid, uuid

In our application we are creating Xml files with an attribute that has a Guid value. This value needed to be consistent between file upgrades. So even if everything else in the file changes, the guid value for the attribute should remain the same.

One obvious solution was to create a static dictionary with the filename and the Guids to be used for them. Then whenever we generate the file, we look up the dictionary for the filename and use the corresponding guid. But this is not feasible because we might scale to 100's of files and didnt want to maintain big list of guids.

So another approach was to make the Guid the same based on the path of the file. Since our file paths and application directory structure are unique, the Guid should be unique for that path. So each time we run an upgrade, the file gets the same guid based on its path. I found one cool way to generate such '[Deterministic Guids](https://web.archive.org/web/20201029003136/http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2008/06/26/generating-deterministic-guids.aspx)' (Thanks Elton Stoneman). It basically does this:

```
private Guid GetDeterministicGuid(string input) 

{ 

//use MD5 hash to get a 16-byte hash of the string: 

MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider(); 

byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input); 

byte[] hashBytes = provider.ComputeHash(inputBytes); 

//generate a guid from the hash: 

Guid hashGuid = new Guid(hashBytes); 

return hashGuid; 

}
```

So given a string, the Guid will always be the same.

Are there any other approaches or recommended ways to doing this? What are the pros or cons of that method?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

As mentioned by @bacar, [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) §4.3 defines a way to create a name-based UUID. The advantage of doing this (over just using a MD5 hash) is that these are guaranteed not to collide with non-named-based UUIDs, and have a very (very) small possibility of collision with other name-based UUIDs.

There's no native support in the .NET Framework for creating these, so I created the [NGuid package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NGuid/#readme-body-tab) that implements the algorithm. It can be used as follows:

```cs
var guid = GuidHelpers.CreateFromName(GuidHelpers.UrlNamespace, filePath);
```

To reduce the risk of collisions with other GUIDs even further, you could create a private GUID to use as the namespace ID (instead of using the URL namespace ID defined in the RFC).

Comment: Note that while this is useful the implementation doesn't quite get RFC4122 correct, so if you're trying to be compatible with another implementation you'll have trouble (try the example in the C code in the RFC appendix).

Comment: @Porges: RFC4122 is incorrect and has errata that fixes the C code (http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=4122&eid=1352). If this implementation is not fully compliant with RFC4122 and its errata, please provide further details; I would like to make it follow the standard.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: I didn't notice that, thanks/sorry! I should always remember to check the errata when reading an RFC... :)

Comment: @Porges: You're welcome/no problem. It boggles the mind that they don't update the RFC in-place with the corrections from the errata. Even a link at the end of the document would be vastly more helpful than relying on the reader to remember to search for errata (hopefully *before* writing an implementation based on the RFC...).

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: if you use the HTML version it has a link to the errata from the header, e.g. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122. I wonder if there's a browser extension to always redirect to the HTML version...

Comment: You should consider contributing this to .NET

.NET repo is here:https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/mscorlib/src/System

Comment: The github was perfect for me, thanks. This gist is a copy of the modifications I made in order to strip out all the unnecessary parts, unrelated to namespace guids. https://gist.github.com/angularsen/92a3ba9d9a94d250accd257f9f5a3d54

Answer (score 35):

This will convert any string into a Guid without having to import an outside assembly.

```
public static Guid ToGuid(string src)
{
    byte[] stringbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(src);
    byte[] hashedBytes = new System.Security.Cryptography
        .SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
        .ComputeHash(stringbytes);
    Array.Resize(ref hashedBytes, 16);
    return new Guid(hashedBytes);
}
```

There are much better ways to generate a unique Guid but this is a way to consistently upgrading a string data key to a Guid data key.

Comment: Found this snippet to be useful when using unique identifier in a database for federated distribution.

Comment: Warning! This code does not generate valid Guids / UUIDs (as bacar also mentioned below). Neither the version nor the type field are set correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just as effective to use the MD5CryptoServiceProvider instead of the SHA1, since MD5 is already 16 bytes in length?

Answer (score 24):

As Rob mentions, your method doesn't generate a UUID, it generates a hash that looks like a UUID.

The [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.3) on UUIDs specifically allows for deterministic (name-based) UUIDs - Versions 3 and 5 use md5 and SHA1(respectively). Most people are probably familiar with version 4, which is random. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) gives a good overview of the versions. (Note that the use of the word 'version' here seems to describe a 'type' of UUID - version 5 doesn't supercede version 4).

There seem to be a few libraries out there for generating version 3/5 UUIDs, including the [python uuid module](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html), [boost.uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html) (C++) and [OSSP UUID](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/). (I haven't looked for any .net ones)

Comment: This is exactly what the original poster is after. UUID already has an algorithm for you to start with a string and convert it into a GUID. UUID version 3 hashes the string with MD5, while version 5 hashes it with SHA1. The important point in creating a "guid" is to makes it "unique" against other GUIDs. The algorithm defines two bits that must be set, as well as a nibble is set to either 3 or 5, depending if it's version 3 or 5.

Comment: Regarding the use of the word "version", RFC 4122 §4.1.3 states: "The version is more accurately a sub-type; again, we retain the term for compatibility."

Comment: I posted some C# code to create v3 and v5 GUIDs on GitHub: https://github.com/LogosBible/Logos.Utility/blob/master/src/Logos.Utility/GuidUtility.cs

Answer (score 4):

You need to make a distinction between instances of the class `Guid`, and identifiers that are globally unique. A "deterministic guid" is actually a hash (as evidenced by your call to `provider.ComputeHash`). Hashes have a much higher chance of collisions (two different strings  happening to produce the same hash) than Guid created via `Guid.NewGuid`.

So the problem with your approach is that you will have to be ok with the possibility that two different paths will produce the same GUID. If you need an identifier that's unique for any given path string, then the easiest thing to do is *just use the string*. If you need the string to be obscured from your users, **encrypt it** - you can use ROT13 or something more powerful...

Attempting to shoehorn something that isn't a pure GUID into the GUID datatype could lead to maintenance problems in future...

Comment: You claim "Hashes have a much higher chance of collisions ... than Guid created via Guid.NewGuid.". Can you elaborate on that? From a mathematical point of View, the number of bits one can set is the same, and both MD5 and SHA1 are cryptographical hashes, specifically designed to lower the probability of (accidental and intentional) hash collisions.

Comment: I would say the main difference is cryptographic hashes map from one infinite space to another fixed space using a function. Imaging a hash that maps variable length strings to 128 bits whereas Guid generates pseudo-random 128 bits. Pseudo-random generation doesn't rely on an initial input but rather by generating the output uniformly in the output space using randomness seeded from the hardware or other means.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is weak, I believe you can do the same thing with SHA-1 and get better results.

BTW, just a personal opinion, dressing a md5 hash up as a GUID does not make it a good GUID. GUIDs by their very nature are non Deterministic. this feels like a cheat. Why not just call a spade a spade and just say its a string rendered hash of the input. you could do that by using this line, rather than the new guid line:

```
string stringHash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this still gives me a string, and I am looking for a GUID...

Comment: Ok, call your hash a "GUID", problem solved. Or is the real problem that you *need* a `Guid` object?

Comment: i wish it were that simple.. :) but yes, i need a 'GUID' object

Comment: "GUIDs by their very nature are non Deterministic" - this is only true of certain types ('versions') of GUIDs. However I agree that "dressing an md5 hash up as a GUID does not make a good GUID" for other reasons as spelt out by @Bradley Grainger and @Rob Fonseca-Ensor, and my answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple solution that should be good enough for things like unit/integration tests:

```
var rnd = new Random(1234); // Seeded random number (deterministic).
Console.WriteLine($"{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}-{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}-{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}-{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}-{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}{rnd.Next(0, 255):x2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a method is implemented by ARM/bicep: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-string#guid

While inefficient and less protected by static compilation, ARM functions can be invoked from .NET code:

```cs
using Azure.Deployments.Expression.Expressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static string Guid(params string[] values)
{
    var parameters = 
       values.Select(arg => new FunctionArgument(JToken.FromObject(arg))).ToArray();

    return ExpressionBuiltInFunctions.Functions
       .EvaluateFunction("guid", parameters, null).Value<string>()!;
}
```