# Test vectors for UUID version 5 (converting hash into guid) generation  algorithm?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, uuid

i'm trying to find some test vectors to check my implementation of [RFC 4122 of UUID version 5](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#sec-4.3).

> **4.3 Algorithm for Creating a Name-Based UUID**

Version 3 of a UUID is for putting an MD5 hash into a GUID.

Version 5 of a UUID is for putting an SHA1 hash into a GUID.

The RFC has sample implementation in C:

```
void uuid_create_sha1_from_name(
   uuid_t *uuid,         /* resulting UUID */
   uuid_t nsid,          /* UUID of the namespace */
   void *name,           /* the name from which to generate a UUID */
   int namelen           /* the length of the name */
);
```

i've written my own implementation in the language that i'm using. Considering the amount of headaches caused by endian vs network order, i am *sure* my implementation is wrong.

i'd like some sample data, e.g.:

```
uuid = NameToGUID(
      {6ba7b811-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8}, //Namespace_URL
      "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515880"); //a url
CheckEquals(
      {8ABAD867-F515-3CF6-BB62-5F0C88B3BB11}, //expected uuid
      uuid);
```

### See also

- [How to Create Deterministic Guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642141/how-to-create-deterministic-guids)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [german Wikipedia entry for UUIDs](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier#Namensbasierte_UUIDs_.28Version_3_und_5.29) got an example for `www.example.org`:

```
6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8 // namespace UUID
www.example.org                      // url
74738ff5-5367-5958-9aee-98fffdcd1876 // expected UUID
```

<strike>Apart from that, Java offers a [UUID class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) you could use to generate test data</strike>. (EDIT: This only seems to be able to generate version 1,2,3 and 4 UUIDs.)

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642141/how-to-create-deterministic-guids/3023431#3023431) in the question you linked that mentions some libraries that can generate version 3/5 UUIDs:

> There seem to be a few libraries out
>   there for generating version 3/5
>   UUIDs, including the [python uuid](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html)
>   module, [boost.uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html) (C++) and [OSSP](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/)
>   UUID. (I haven't looked for any .net
>   ones)

---

**OP Edit**

The example on the DE wikipedia has a slight mistake:

- it claims to be using the `DNS` name `www.example.org`
- the given ASCII byte sequence is for `www.example.com`
- but the SHA1 hash is using `www.example.org`.

> i would edit the page to change the byte sequence from
>      `0x63 0x6f 0x6d` "com"
>   to
>      `0x6f 0x72 0x67` "org"
>
> but i don't speak german, don't want to create an account, and am just all around too lazy

The example boils down to

```
Namespace_DNS: {6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8}
Name:          "www.example.org"
```

concatenate the byte sequences:

```
Bytes:         6b a7 b8 10 9d ad 11 d1 80 b4 00 c0 4f d4 30 c8   {6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8}
               77 77 77 2e 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 6f 72 67      "www.example.org"
```

Hash the byte sequence with SHA1, and copy most of it directly into a UUID:

```
SHA1 Digest:   74738ff5 5367 e958 9aee98fffdcd187694028007
UUID (v5):     74738ff5-5367-5958-9aee-98fffdcd1876
                             ^    ^
```

And take note of the conversion of one of the nibbles to `5` (to signify version 5).
And the top 2 bits of another byte are set to binary `10xxxxxx`.

Comment: as far as I know Java UUID class doesn't support version 5 only 1-4 and even that is only on JDK6 since before you don't have a native JDK way for obtaining the MAC address

Comment: @Asaf: Yeah, I saw that right after proposing it. Striked the part to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for spotting that, I'll edit the Wikipedia page.