# Is there any way to generate the same UUID from a String

Tags: java, uuid

I am wondering if there is a way to generate the same UUID based on a `String.` 
I tried with UUID, it looks like it does not provide this feature.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

You can use UUID this way to get always the same UUID for your input String:

```
 String aString="JUST_A_TEST_STRING";
 String result = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(aString.getBytes()).toString();
```

Comment: any js equivalent?

Comment: any PHP equivalent? What is the algorithm behind this?

Comment: @mika [This PHP UUID library](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) is somewhat equivalent. You can generate the same UUID for the given namespace + string. You can do something like: `Uuid::uuid3(Uuid::NAMESPACE_DNS, 'TEST STRING')->toString();` It uses md5 hashing in this example. [Additional info on UUID namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776880/1514049)

Comment: is there any way I can decode this UUID to original String ?

Comment: If the original string is part of a known set of strings (stored in your db for example), you can generate the UUID for each string and compare with the UUID you want to decode. Otherwise, it is not "technically" possible

Comment: what are the chances that the generated UUID from a given string will clash with a UUID generated from another string?

Comment: @Groppe very small, similar to the chances that an MD5 (UUIDv3) or SHA1 (UUIDv5) hash clash for a given string

Comment: I know that we can create UUID from a string but I want to know if we can create String reverse back from UUID ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do UUID.fromString?

Comment: @opticyclic UUID.fromString does not generate a new UUID based on the input, but expects an existing valid UUID string representation as input.

Comment: `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` generates MD5 UUIDs. This does not work if the input String was generated by a SHA1 function.

Answer (score 19):

`UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes()` only generates MD5 UUIDs. However, SHA1 is preferred over MD5, *if backward compatibility is not an issue*.

The utility class below generates MD5 UUIDs and SHA-1 UUIDs. Feel free to use and share.

```java
package com.example;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Generates UUIDv3 (MD5) and UUIDv5 (SHA1).
 *
 * It is fully compliant with RFC-4122.
 */
public class HashUuid {

    private static final int V3 = 3; // MD5
    private static final int V5 = 5; // SHA-1

    private static final String HASH_V3 = "MD5";
    private static final String HASH_V5 = "SHA-1";

    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_DNS = new UUID(0x6ba7b8109dad11d1L, 0x80b400c04fd430c8L);
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_URL = new UUID(0x6ba7b8119dad11d1L, 0x80b400c04fd430c8L);
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_OID = new UUID(0x6ba7b8129dad11d1L, 0x80b400c04fd430c8L);
    public static final UUID NAMESPACE_X500 = new UUID(0x6ba7b8149dad11d1L, 0x80b400c04fd430c8L);

    public static UUID v3(String name) {
        return generate(V3, HASH_V3, null, name);
    }

    public static UUID v5(String name) {
        return generate(V5, HASH_V5, null, name);
    }

    public static UUID v3(UUID namespace, String name) {
        return generate(V3, HASH_V3, namespace, name);
    }

    public static UUID v5(UUID namespace, String name) {
        return generate(V5, HASH_V5, namespace, name);
    }

    private static UUID generate(int version, String algorithm, UUID namespace, String name) {

        MessageDigest hasher = hasher(algorithm);

        if (namespace != null) {
            ByteBuffer ns = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
            ns.putLong(namespace.getMostSignificantBits());
            ns.putLong(namespace.getLeastSignificantBits());
            hasher.update(ns.array());
        }

        hasher.update(name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        ByteBuffer hash = ByteBuffer.wrap(hasher.digest());

        final long msb = (hash.getLong() & 0xffffffffffff0fffL) | (version & 0x0f) << 12;
        final long lsb = (hash.getLong() & 0x3fffffffffffffffL) | 0x8000000000000000L;

        return new UUID(msb, lsb);
    }

    private static MessageDigest hasher(String algorithm) {
        try {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s not supported.", algorithm));
        }
    }

    /**
     * For tests!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UUID namespace = UUID.randomUUID();
        String name = "JUST_A_TEST_STRING";

        System.out.println(String.format("UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes():     '%s'", UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(name.getBytes())));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(String.format("HashUuid.v3(name):            '%s'", HashUuid.v3(name)));
        System.out.println(String.format("HashUuid.v5(name):            '%s'", HashUuid.v5(name)));
        System.out.println(String.format("HashUuid.v3(namespace, name): '%s'", HashUuid.v3(namespace, name)));
        System.out.println(String.format("HashUuid.v5(namespace, name): '%s'", HashUuid.v5(namespace, name)));
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes():     '9e120341-627f-32be-8393-58b5d655b751'

HashUuid.v3(name):            '9e120341-627f-32be-8393-58b5d655b751'
HashUuid.v5(name):            'e4586bed-032a-5ae6-9883-331cd94c4ffa'
HashUuid.v3(namespace, name): 'f0043437-723b-308f-a6c0-74ec36ddf9c2'
HashUuid.v5(namespace, name): '18a45fd8-8fab-5647-aad7-1d3264932180'
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`uuid-creator`](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator). See this example:

```java
// Create a UUIDv5 (SHA1)
String name = "JUST_A_TEST_STRING";
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1(name);
```

Comment: Why do you think that SHA1 should be preferred over MD5 when generating a UUID?

Comment: I don't think it should always be preferred. It depends on the case. RFC-4122, in its section 4.3, says that If backward compatibility is not an issue, SHA-1 is preferred. I'll fix my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You should use **UUID v5.**

> Version-3 and version-5 UUIDs are generated by hashing a namespace identifier and name. Version 3 uses MD5 as the hashing algorithm, and version 5 uses SHA-1.[1](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4) - *wikipedia*

UUID v5 requires a **namespace**. That namespace should be a UUID v4, which you can just [generate online](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4). The namespace assures that for a given input, the output will always be the same.

A possible implementation of UUID v5 can be found [here](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator):

```
<!-- https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.f4b6a3/uuid-creator -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.f4b6a3</groupId>
  <artifactId>uuid-creator</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It can be used as follows:

```
UUID namespace = ; // todo generate a UUID v4.
String input = "input";
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1(namespace, input);
```

*(In a way, the namespace acts like a seed would, for a random number generator. By contrast, while a seed is supposed to be random, our namespace is a constant. And that forces our generator to always produce the same value for a given input.)*

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a Javascript alternative, look at [uuid-by-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-by-string) which also gives option to use SHA-1 or MD5 hash functions.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a javascript alternative :)