# Creating same UUID from a string QT5

Tags: qt, qt5, uuid

I would like to create UUID from a string so that I can generate the same UUID for the particular string input. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059530/is-there-any-way-to-generate-the-same-uuid-from-a-string) tells how to do it in Java, but is there any way to achieve it in QT5?

Comment: Have you looked at [`QUuid`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have member function to create same Uuid from a string like "device_ID_5721". It only has function that takes string in the format of another Uuid or a function that takes string and reference to another quuid which obviously create different Uuid for the same string.

Comment: _it doesn't have member function to create same Uuid from a string_ Did you see: [QUuid::fromString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html#fromString)?

Comment: I'm struggling to work out exactly what `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` does in the java example but based on [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/uuid_nameuuidfrombytes.htm) `QUuid::createUuidV3(QUuid{}, aString)` *might* be the UUID generator you want.

Comment: @scopchanov that function return null for the string "'device_ID_5721"

Comment: Yes, `fromString` expects the UUID in a particular format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes(byte%5B%5D)) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/uuid_nameuuidfrombytes.htm) the following java...

```
// Java
String aString="JUST_A_TEST_STRING";
String result = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(aString.getBytes()).toString();
```

uses `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` to generate a type 3 MD5 digest based UUID from the byte data supplied.

The equivalent C++ using `QUuid` is, I think...

```
// C++
QString aString("JUST_A_TEST_STRING");
QString result = QUuid::createUuidV3(QUuid{}, aString).toString();
```