# Likelihood of Collision

Tags: cryptography, hash-collision

I want to hash an internal account number and use the result as a unique public identifier for an account record. The identifier is limited to 40 characters.  I have approximately 250 records with unique account numbers.

What is less likely to result in a collision.

1. Taking the SHA-1 of the SHA-256 hash of the account number.
2. Taking the SHA-256 of the account number and picking out 40 characters.

Comment: Taking a hash of an account number will not encrypt it in any commonly understood sense of the term "encryption". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to ignore the possibility of SHA collisions in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014090/is-it-safe-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-sha-collisions-in-practice)

Comment: I want to associate a value that uniquely represents an account number without having to maintain a table of unique IDs to Account Numbers.

Comment: @AgostBiro - I edited my question and replaced "encrypt" with "hash"

Comment: @MichaelStarkie I'm confused why you wouldn't just use the account number publicly? Hashing it with SHA doesn't conceal it.

Comment: You could use a keyed hash function if you really want to conceal the account number, but then you have to do key management. In most cases it's much easier to store an additional uuid to account number mapping.

Comment: Or just salt them with a large secret, which is simple.

Comment: @RobNapier secret salt still needs key management. I'm concerned OP expects confidentiality from the SHA hash which it doesn't provide.

Comment: @AgostBiro What do you mean here by "key management" beyond "keep a single secret, secret?" This is commonly done on servers, and does provide confidentiality in this use case. The only reason SHA won't provide confidentiality is because the account list is probably quite small so it can be brute forced. A single large pepper (secret salt) will fix that.

Comment: @RobNapier There are secrets and then there are secrets. If a database password is exposed, it can be changed and hopefully the DB is on a private network anyway. If the secret salt from your proposed solution is exposed then the account numbers are forever exposed and there is nothing OP can do about it which is why the salt should be treated as a cryptographic key.

Comment: So it seems I'm trying to use a hash function to conceal an artifact which is not the purpose of a hash function.  I'm inclined to just generate my own UUID.  Is there a way I can do this programmatically using other account artifacts without having to expand database tables and other headaches?

Comment: @MichaelStarkie I don't think you can avoid storing additional data in order to conceal the account numbers unfortunately. It's either a cryptographic key or an additional account number to uuid mapping in your DB.

Comment: @AgostBiro What about using a keyed hash function with a statically defined large random string that only we know about?  It would be easy to maintain and, for the sake of argument, let's assume the secret is safe with us.  Random but never changing.

Comment: @MichaelStarkie well if you can secure it as a cryptographic key, then go for it, but frankly, in my experience you would be much better served by maintaining an additional uuid to account number mapping even if it seems painful to set up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These approaches are identical (*), so you should use the second one. There is no reason to inject SHA-1 into the system. Any selection of bits out of SHA-256 are independent and "effectively random."

An alternate solution that may be convenient is to [turn these into v5 UUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64013733/97337). If you keep your namespace secret (which is allowed), this may be a very nice way to do what you're describing.

(*) There are some subtleties around the fact that your using "characters" rather than bytes here, and you could get a larger space in 40 "characters" by using a better encoding than you're likely using. It's possible the spaces are a little different based on how you're actually encoding. But it deeply doesn't matter. These spaces are enormous, and the two approaches will be the same in practice, so use the one that only needs one algorithm.

---

Another approach that may meet your needs better is to stretch the identifiers. If the space is sufficiently sparse (i.e if the number of possible identifiers is dramatically larger than the number of actually used identifiers), then stretching algorithms like PBKDF2 are designed to handle exactly that. They are expensive to compute, but you can tune their cost to match your security requirements.

The general problem with just hashing is that hashes are very fast, and if your space of possible identifiers is very small, then it's easy to brute force. Stretching algorithms make the cost of guessing arbitrarily expensive, so large spaces are impractical to brute force. They do this without requiring any secrets, which is nice. The general approach is:

- Select a "salt" value. This can be publicly known. It does not matter. For this particular use case, because every account number is different, you can select a single global salt. (If the protected data could be the same, then it's important to have different salts for each record.)
- Compute `PBKDF2(salt, iterations, length, payload)`

The number of iterations tunes how slow this operation is. The output is "effectively random" (just like a hash) and can be used in the same ways.

A common target for iterations is a value that delivers around 80-100ms. This is fairly fast on the server, but is extremely slow for brute-forcing large spaces, even if the attacker has better hardware than yours. Ideally your space should take at least millions of years to brute force (seriously; this is the kind of headroom we typically like in security; I personally target trillions of years). If it's smaller than a few years, then it probably can be brute forced quickly by throwing more hardware at it.

(Of course all of these choices can be turned based on your attack model. It depends on how dedicated and well-funded you expect attacks to be.)

Answer (score 0):

A 40 character ID is 320 bits, which gives you plenty of space. With only 250 records, you can easily fit a unique counter into that. Three digits is only 24 bits, and you have the range 000 to 999 to play with. Fill up the rest of the ID with, say, the hex expression of part of the SHA-256 hash. With a 3-digit ID, that leaves 37 places for hex which covers 37*4 = 148 bits of the Sha-256 output.

You may want to put the counter in the middle of the hex string in a fixed position instead of at the beginning or end to make it less obvious.

```
<11 hex chars><3 digit ID><26 hex chars>
```