# How can I generate a UUID v4 that starts with '00' using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, uuid

How to generate a valid UUID v4 that starts with specific characters?

Suppose I want to generate UUID v4 that starts with `00` – short of looping through random UUIDs until I get UUID that starts with `00`, is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: find a UUIDv4 generator, modify it to your specs - or simply replace the first two characters with `00` - since a v4 UUID is purely random, this is perfectly valid to do

Comment: I presume you're aware, but doing this will increase [collision probability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876263/438273) (in a insignificant way, practically, of course) — it might be useful to simply prefix the full UUID if your string length isn't constrained — or just prefix a different UID schema (e.g. [`nanoid`](https://github.com/ai/nanoid#comparison-with-uuid)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the first two characters of a generated UUID and prepend `"00"` in its place.

```js
console.log('00' + crypto.randomUUID().slice(2));
```

Comment: This answers it, but this answer providers more context https://stackoverflow.com/a/76302739/21936721