# Uniquely Identify android devices

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android, and I have a unique problem in front of me. Basically, I need to identify the android device using some unique ID, which shouldn't change when the app is reinstalled. This has to survive factory reset as well. This is not to do something sketchy or show ads, It's just to uniquely identify and maintain the license per device.

I have tried using the following code.

```
val androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

But it only works as long as the app is built by the same user. E.g. If the unique ID returns 1234 in my device, it returns 5678 in when the app is built in another android studio. Since we have 3 people working on this app, we are being cornered to build the app by utilizing one android studio all the time.

Please let me know if there is any way we could uniquely identify the devices. These devices might not have google play services, hence we cannot use anything dependent on that.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: You can try this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059595/7521690

Comment: Android does not provide unique Ids that do not change after a factory reset.