# Generate UUID from name space?

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

Trying to generate a client Id, based on 2 unique strings.
This should end up being the same UUID as generated in the server, from same I'ds.

With Javascript it looks something like this:

```
uuidv5(id1 + id2 , uuidv5.DNS);
```

Can't seem to find a way of generating this on Swift, NSUUID only can generate a UUID from nothing

```
NSUUID().uuidString
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
NSUUID(namespace: id1 + id2).uuidString
```

**Edit**

Example:

```
let sorted = ["5a23dbfb2626b400190998fc", "5pCAvA7h8k9JuErRn"]
let appended = sorted.seperaredStringBy("-")
let result = uuidv5(appended , uuidv5.DNS)

//results:
2522b097-8532-548e-a18b-9366c6511b5e
```

Comment: There is `initWithUUIDString:` and `initWithUUIDBytes:` methods. Now the question, is what does `uuidv5(id1 + id2 , uuidv5.DNS)` exactly? Note that in Swift 3+ you should use `UUID` instead of `NSUUID` that provide the same methods (`init(uuidString:)`)

Comment: @Larme Thanks for quick response. As far I understand, initWithUUID will generate a UUID object from a UUID String. I am looking for a way of appending 2 strings (not UUID) then creating from result a UUID, that will be unique. And no matter were and when would be generated, will stay same from the same Id's

Comment: At least you should add an example of added string and the output of generating a UUID from it... so might be able to compare it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776880/4156845 you can calculate the sha1 bytes by yourself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Swift standard library or the Foundation framework have no built-in method for version 5 UUIDs, as far as I know.

Here is a possible implementation for version 3 and version 5 UUIDs, taken from the description at [Generating v5 UUID. What is name and namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867405/generating-v5-uuid-what-is-name-and-namespace/28776880#28776880) and the reference implementation in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

(Updated for Swift 4 and later.)

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

extension UUID {

    enum UUIDVersion: Int {
        case v3 = 3
        case v5 = 5
    }

    enum UUIDv5NameSpace: String {
        case dns  = "6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8"
        case url  = "6ba7b811-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8"
        case oid  = "6ba7b812-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8"
        case x500 = "6ba7b814-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8"
    }

    init(version: UUIDVersion, name: String, nameSpace: UUIDv5NameSpace) {
        // Get UUID bytes from name space:
        var spaceUID = UUID(uuidString: nameSpace.rawValue)!.uuid
        var data = withUnsafePointer(to: &spaceUID) { [count =  MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: spaceUID)] in
            Data(bytes: $0, count: count)
        }

        // Append name string in UTF-8 encoding:
        data.append(contentsOf: name.utf8)

        // Compute digest (MD5 or SHA1, depending on the version):
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> Void in
            switch version {
            case .v3:
                _ = CC_MD5(ptr.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
            case .v5:
                _ = CC_SHA1(ptr.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
            }
        }

        // Set version bits:
        digest[6] &= 0x0F
        digest[6] |= UInt8(version.rawValue) << 4
        // Set variant bits:
        digest[8] &= 0x3F
        digest[8] |= 0x80

        // Create UUID from digest:
        self = NSUUID(uuidBytes: digest) as UUID
    }
}
```

Example 1 (Your case):

```
let uuid = UUID(version: .v5, name: "5a23dbfb2626b400190998fc-5pCAvA7h8k9JuErRn", nameSpace: .dns)
print(uuid) // 2522B097-8532-548E-A18B-9366C6511B5E
```

Example 2 (From Appendix B in RFC 4122, as corrected in the [Errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=4122)):

```
let uuid = UUID(version: .v3, name: "www.widgets.com", nameSpace: .dns)
print(uuid) //3D813CBB-47FB-32BA-91DF-831E1593AC29
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you.

Comment: var data = withUnsafePointer(to: &spaceUID) {
            Data(bytes: $0, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: spaceUID))
 }                           
I got “Overlapping accesses to 'spaceUID', but modification requires exclusive access; ; consider copying to a local variable withUnsafePointer” error with this part. So changed it as                                                                                  
   var data = withUnsafePointer(to: &spaceUID, { [s = spaceUID] b in
            return Data(bytes: b, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: s))
})

Comment: @User18474728: You are right, that is a consequence of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md. I have updated the code to fix that issue and also another warning. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: hi, is there a objc version.

Answer (score 1):

the objc version, in case someone need it.

```objectivec
+ (CBUUID *)UUIDWithNamespace:(NSString *)namespace name:(NSString *)name version:(int)version
{
    if (namespace.length <= 0 || name == nil  ) { return nil; }
    if (!(version == 3        || version == 5)) { return nil; }
    CBUUID *namespaceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:namespace];
    if (namespaceUUID == nil) { return nil; }
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [data appendData:namespaceUUID.data];
    [data appendData:[name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if (version == 3) {
        CC_MD5(data.bytes, (int)data.length, hash);
    } else if (version == 5) {
        CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (int)data.length, hash);
    }
    unsigned char result[16];
    memcpy(result, hash, 16);
    result[6] &= 0x0F;
    result[6] |= (((unsigned char)version) << 4);
    result[8] &= 0x3F;
    result[8] |= 0x80;
    return [CBUUID UUIDWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:result length:16]];
}
```