# C# Generate a GUID similar to Python's UUID5

Tags: c#, python, guid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Create Deterministic Guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642141/how-to-create-deterministic-guids)

Using C#, I want to generate a GUID using a SHA-1 hash of a namespace UUID and a name, just like Python's UUID5

```
uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'python.org')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#example

Comment: That link includes a reference to @Bradley Grainger's code on Github to do this: https://github.com/LogosBible/Logos.Utility/blob/master/src/Logos.Utility/GuidUtility.cs

Comment: So that's what it's called :) Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a good name.  I had trouble finding it too. :)