# Can EntityFramework core use deterministic Guids?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to inject a Guid provider to aspnet / EF core so that two test runs produces the identical database content?

I'd like to diff the dump of two databases but randomised ids are a problem. I currently remove the ids but it makes the diff less than idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this behavior with [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDefaultValue(MyGuidProvider());
```

As for actually creating `MyGuidProvider()` I unfortunately can't be of much help, you can try checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642141/how-to-create-deterministic-guids)